# send image data from android device to web-server

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, ftp

I'm developing a server-client web based application. Clients are mobile phones (android) which should send their data to the server. Their data includes (among other things) images which may be up to 1MB in size. What is the best way for sending these images to the server? A web service? FTP? or something else? Provided we have fast and stable mobile internet connection, can we safely use web service? I can imagine that android device sends image data as raw binary to the webservice and webservice writes these data into database, then website can use these data to display images. Is it a good idea to use webservice for this scenario (specially for large images being up to 1MB in size)? or I should other methods?

Comment: call a webservice to post the data. also it will be better if you save the data onto fielsystem and just put the url in database. then at the time of retrieval read the path and directly show the image , this will save you loads of cpu cycles and money

Comment: You can use Webservice and send your image as a byte array using MultiPart entity.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, what do you mean exactly by posting the data? you mean android device should post data to web server? as a file or as binary data?

Comment: thanks PG_Android, so you mean sending byte array is better?